# Showing Data 12 months in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the query:

```
SELECT MONTH(tgl) AS month, SUM(jumlahA) AS A, SUM(jumlahB) AS B
FROM tabel where YEAR(tgl)='2002' GROUP BY MONTH(tgl) order by 1;
```

The Result is:

```
month   A       B
----------------------
1       85      0
2       38      0
9       34      23
```

The problem is how to show the data completely a year (12 months) in PHP where the month has no data put 0 to A and B. Actually I want to create bar graphic with month axis (jan, feb, ..., des)

**UPDATE**

Here goes some of my PHP code:

```
echo "<categories>\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Jan' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Feb' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Mar' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Apr' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Mei' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Jun' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Jul' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Agu' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Sept' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Okt' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Nop' />\n"; 
    echo "<category name='Des' />\n"; 
echo "</categories>\n";

echo "<dataset seriesname='Hulu' color='AFD8F8'>"; 
$strQuery="SELECT MONTH(tgl) AS month, SUM(jumlahA) AS A, SUM(jumlahB) AS B FROM tabel where YEAR(tgl)='2002' GROUP BY MONTH(tgl) order by 1"; 
$hasil=mysql_query($strQuery); 
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) { 
    echo "<set value='".$data[1]."' />"; 
} 
echo "</dataset>";
```

Comment: Show us your PHP code.

Comment: echo "<categories>\n";
echo "<category name='Jan' />\n";
echo "<category name='Feb' />\n";
echo "<category name='Mar' />\n";
echo "<category name='Apr' />\n";
echo "<category name='Mei' />\n";
echo "<category name='Jun' />\n";
echo "<category name='Jul' />\n";
echo "<category name='Agu' />\n";
echo "<category name='Sept' />\n";
echo "<category name='Okt' />\n";
echo "<category name='Nop' />\n";
echo "<category name='Des' />\n";
echo "</categories>\n";

Comment: echo "<dataset seriesname='Hulu' color='AFD8F8'>";
 $strQuery="SELECT MONTH(tgl) AS month, SUM(jumlahA) AS A, SUM(jumlahB) AS B FROM tabel where YEAR(tgl)='2002' GROUP BY MONTH(tgl) order by 1";
$hasil=mysql_query($strQuery);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
 echo "<set value='".$data[1]."' />";
 } 
echo   "</dataset>";

Answer (score 1):

Make an `array` with the same values tha will be returned from `MONTH(tgl) AS month`. Assuming those values are the same of the categories(if not you may change it), do something like this:

```
$months = array('Jan'=>null, 'Feb'=>null, 'Mar'=>null, 'Apr'=>null, 'Mei'=>null, 
'Jun'=>null, 'Jul'=>null, 'Agu'=>null, 'Sept'=>null, 'Okt'=>null, 'Nop'=>null, 'Des'=>null);
```

Nice. Now change your `while` to this:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) { 
    $months[$data[0]] = "<set value='".$data[1]."' />"; 
}
```

Now, in the array you got all the months each one with it respectively value. The months that have no value are `NULL`s. Now it's easy:

```
foreach ($months as $month) {
    if ($month) {
        echo $month;
    }
    else {
        echo "<set value='0' />";
    }
}
```

This came right from my mind, I didn't tested it and I hope it works and helps!

Comment: Thanks DontVoteMeDownto I tested your coding

Comment: Thanks to DontVoteMeDown. I tested your coding but any error like "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\prj\lumpur\datagrafik\tumpahan_minyak\test2.php on line 11" The error pointed to code foreach ($month in $months)

Comment: Because return value from MONTH(tgl) AS month is numeric, I change  $months became $months = array('Jan'=>1, 'Feb'=>2, 'Mar'=>3, 'Apr'=>4, 'Mei'=>5, 'Jun'=>6, 'Jul'=>7, 'Agu'=>8, 'Sept'=>9, 'Okt'=>10, 'Nop'=>11, 'Des'=>12); But still same error

Comment: @IrwanSetiawan sorry, I've confused PHP with JavaScript. Look at the change on the `foreach` statement. In case of you month field come as a number from you database, you have to change your array to this `array(1=>null, 2=>null` and so on, because the *key* will be the month and the *value* the quantity.

Comment: Case Closed :) Thanks to DontVoteMeDown

$months = array('Jan'=>1, 'Feb'=>2, 'Mar'=>3, 'Apr'=>4, 'Mei'=>5, 'Jun'=>6, 'Jul'=>7, 'Agu'=>8, 'Sept'=>9, 'Okt'=>10, 'Nop'=>11, 'Des'=>12); 

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) {
    $monthx[]=$data[0];
    $month[$data[0]] = "<set value='".$data[1]."' />"; 
} 

echo   "<dataset seriesname='Hulu' color='AFD8F8'>";
foreach ($months as $mon) {
    if (in_array($mon, $monthx)) {
        echo $month[$mon];
    }
    else {
        echo "<set value='0' />";
    }
}

Comment: @IrwanSetiawan nice to hear it.

Comment: don't forget htmlentities~